# facebook graph api /me/friends started to return empty with test users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Before this is tagged as a duplicate (or infinitycate, as I've seen searching here), I know facebook graph api friends request returns only friends who have the app installed.

That being said, I have my app on develop stage, and I've created several test users and set friendships among them. I've been able to get their friends (only the ones I've setted as friends of the logged one). Thus far, all OK.

The problem I have is something that happened me twice; after I log in into facebook with a test user (one time from desktop PC, another with android app), I've started to receive the /me/friends request empty. I have tried loggin off and on again, erasing cache & data, looking for some profile configuration... with no luck. I haven't seen any policy regarding loggin test users and loosing some functionality... any ideas?

Regars!

Comment: Did those test users grant `user_friends` permission to your app as well? For your app to be able to see user `B` when friends of user `A` are requested, _both_ need to have granted that permission.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thanks for your answer! Yes, they have both the user_friend permission. I have that permission set in code at login, and I believe the permission is OK since they both are shown to each other until y log in with the facebook app... then, B stops seeing A and A stops seeing B...

Comment: Test users should function the same as regular users in this case. I would suggest reporting this as a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs, including specific user ids and access tokens.